# Can you identify this bird?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

Can somebody please identify this bird for me?

I spotted this in July 2012 while birding in [Ranganthittu Bird Sanctuary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranganthittu_Bird_Sanctuary).

[image: unknown bird]

Comment: A snowy egret that got "into" some fermented canteloupe, then slept it off.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a Cattle Egret ([Bubulcus ibis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubulcus_ibis)), which is a heron in its breeding plumage. When not breeding, the bird is white. See the images for comparision:

[image]

Breeding cattle egret with colored feathers.

[image]

Nonbreeding cattle egret, completely white.

Comment: Just an addition, this is the bird's breeding plumage. Non-breeding individuals are just white.

Comment: Good point, I added it to the answer.